# Is there any way to enable simple web server HTTP request logging on Spark?

Tags: java, jetty, spark-java

I've looked through the entirety of the [Spark documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html), but don't see anything at all about logging. I know that Spark uses an embedded version of the [Jetty web server](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-logging.html), but it seems like there may not be a way to enable Jetty logging without actually going in and changing Spark framework code.

I was hoping to have all HTTP requests to the server logged in the [Common Log Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format). Right now, when I start the server, I see this followed by silence no matter how many requests I throw at it:

```
[Thread-1] INFO spark.webserver.SparkServer - == Spark has ignited ...
[Thread-1] INFO spark.webserver.SparkServer - >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567
[Thread-1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.0.2.v20130417
[Thread-1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@46f24fce{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4567}
```

My best idea at the moment is to roll my own logging system in a `before` filter. For example:

```
before((req, res) -> {
    System.out.println("Request from " + req.ip() + " received - " + req.userAgent());
});
```

But it seems that this functionality *should* be built-in to this framework, and I'm just not seeing it. I figure that a relatively popular web framework (with over 3,000 stars [on Github](https://github.com/perwendel/spark)) would have logging built-in for its web server, right?

Comment: Did you ever get a suitable solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what spark is, but If Jetty isn't too old there, you should be able to provide a slf4j binding (and possibly logging implementation if not using Simple one) such as Simple SLF4J. (See http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)

If you use Simple SLF4J binding you can configure it (including log level or logging file) through JVM system properties as documented in Javadoc: http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html

Comment: Thanks, but that wiki page is for a similarly named but totally different project. Here's the link to the Spark framework I'm referring to: https://github.com/perwendel/spark

Answer (score 0):

Old question but for all coming around here: Just define a logger in you application class like this:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourCurrent.class);
```

now you are able to log your own messages with spark logging adapter.

```
LOG.error("missing whatever");
```